# Lookup doesn't work on field that has taxonomy field

Tags: sharepoint-addin, lookup-column, site-column, visual-studio-2015

Is there any reason why **lookup** field in one list would stop working when **taxonomy** field is added to other list that lookup is referenced to? Before adding the taxonomy field lookup was working just fine...I'm developing a 2013 sharepoint hosted app in **Visual studio 2015**, by adding lists, site columns etc.

Important notice, lookup field's **ShowField** property is refernced to **Title** to the first list, not Taxonomy. And I double checked the order in features so that shouldn't be the problem. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!